# How to capture multiple log streams from a single Docker container?

Tags: java, docker, logging

Let's say I have a Java web app deployed in Docker, with several components producing logs within the container:

- Web application itself, logging to `STDOUT` and `STDERR`
- Application server, logging to `server.log`
- JVM, logging GC events to `gc.log`
- Others, e.g. underlying Linux OS

The application logs are routed to Splunk, but how should we retrieve logs for other components?

It seems there are at least two options:

- Log everything to `STDOUT`. Not ideal as this mixes logs and produces output that is more complex to separate, as different components produce logs in different formats.
- Use sidecar containers for each process other than the main process, and have those sidecars retrieve the logs from e.g. `server.log` and `gc.log`, and pipe them to `STDOUT`. Better, but this can have a significant impact on disk usage.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR; Don't mix log streams, using sidecar is the better solution and doesn't have "significant impact" on disk usage.  Use sidecars to redirect logs to stdout and lean on the container ecosystem's capability to read individual container's log.

*Note*:  Sidecar with log redirection logic does not have significant overhead.  I'm quoting [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#streaming-sidecar-container) in support of this - "The logic behind redirecting logs is minimal, so it's hardly a significant overhead"

---

The key is not to mix-up the log streams, as separating single stream from mixed log stream later could be tedious, if not impossible (with log events like exception stack trace which span multiple lines).  For instance, if you mix up log streams, to analyze GC you would need to separate out GC log events alone, before feeding it into your tool of choice.

Solution is to use [side-car pattern](https://www.magalix.com/blog/the-sidecar-pattern), detailed with example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/)

Follow [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).  Have each sidecar tail one log file and stream it to stdout.  To achieve this, all the sidecars should have access to webapp container's log volume mount (say /var/log) and the webapp should write all its log to shared volume mount(s).

The webapp will write its own log to stdout (Say through [ConsoleAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/ConsoleAppender.html) of LogBack or Log4j) and any other additional log files under shared volume mount (say  /var/log).  As an example, for GC log, set the JVM argument, to have the log generate beneath shared volume mount, `-Xloggc:/var/log/mywebapp/gc.log`.

For each additional log file, you would need a sidecar tailing (redirecting) log to stdout.  So in your case you would need three sidecars, one for gc.log, one for server.log and another for /var/log/syslog

A sample sidecar container definition excerpt is given below.

```
  - name: count-log-1
    image: busybox
    args: [/bin/sh, -c, 'tail -n+1 -f /var/log/mywebapp/gc.log']
    volumeMounts:
    - name: varlog
      mountPath: /var/log
```

The above example shows a single sidecar definition redirecting/tailing log file from /var/log shared volume mount to stdout.  This example was copied from [this Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#streaming-sidecar-container).

Comment: Thanks for this. The disk usage I was thinking of was due to writing logs to a file as opposed to streaming them to stdout directly using e.g. ConsoleAppender. The disk usage of my main container will increase as it writes more output to e.g. /var/log/mywebapp/gc.log. As you say, the sidecar approach itself adds minimal overhead.

Comment: Well, if the intent is to move from disk pressure to memory pressure, then first the log event originator should support it (could -Xloggc JVM argument write to socket instead of file?), second write should be asynchronous/non-blocking (otherwise application can fail in unexpected ways, along with back pressure on your web/worker-threads that does blocking logging) and third fine tune logging configuration, unless you could afford some lost log events (should you almost exhaust the buffer capacity or during JVM stop event).

Comment: Another example that comes to my mind, though not exactly logging, is that, AWS Fargate containers send trace information to X-Ray sidecars, which in-turn sends it to AWS X-Ray service.  Likewise you could have a sidecar listening for remote log events from main application and stream it to stdout stream, but there are associated complications.  In short, switching away from local file is not something that is to be taken lightly, as otherwise will end up adding significant accidental complexity.